The importance of the Balmer spectrum
Why are Balmer spectra important? Can someone give examples of reconstruction a category by its spectrum (in some sense)?
It would also be interesting to see applications of Balmer spectra to the calculation of Picard groups of a category.
The categories of "motivic" nature are especially interesting.
P.S. I am familiar with some of Balmer's texts (and with subsequent works with Gallauer).

In ancient times, people believed that when you pass from the scheme $X$ to its derived category, you lose a lot of information. After Bondal-Orlov you know that it is not the case with nice positivity (or negativity) of the canonical divisor. Balmer's observation is that if you add the tensor structure, you can reconstruct the scheme. Not only that, it gives you an explicit procedure to construct it, underlying topological space and structure sheaf included.

Thanks. Of course, I understand that tensor triangulated equivalence allows you to say much more than just triangulated (this is where the "advertisement" in Balmer's article begins). The results are also known in the spirit of the fact that $Spc(D^{perf}(X))$
reconstructs the scheme $X$
itself (for $X$
qcqs) - by Thomason’s classification.But is the ringed space structure necessary for these results outside the derived categories of sheaves?
